# How to run a select amount of code n amount of times where user input is n

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, input, output

I'm having some trouble trying to repeat a certain part of code n times where n is user input. It would start off something like

```
roominput = int(input("How many rooms do you require painting?"))
```

The user would then input with an `integer(n)` and a select part of the program would repeat n amount of times, asking for the room name, room's dimensions and colour of paint for the wall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
roominput = int(input("How many rooms do you require painting?"))
for i in range(roominput):
    # ask your questions here, it will be executed roominput times
    # ask room name - room_name = input("What is the room name?")
    # ask room's dimensions - room_dimension = int(input("What is the room's dimensions?"))
    # ask paint for the wall - paint = input("What is the wall paint color?")
```

Comment: should be `range(1, roominput)` if a value of 2 will ask for the details three times

Comment: That's not true... it is exactly 5 times if roominput = 5 for example. With your solution it will run 4 times